# Regular expression to match last pattern of text

Tags: regex

I have text like that: "2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654", Witch means VERSION-SNAPSHOT-BUILD.

1. I need to exclude the first part: "2.3.7-SNAPSHOT" separately
2. And the build number "654" separately

so in my case i need two regex, i tried to do this:

```
[\d\.]
```

but it's give me all the numbers togohter.
can you help me to build those two regex's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python:

```
text = "2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654"
separator = "-"
text_list = text.split(separator)
number = text_list[-1]
first_part = text.replace(number, "")[:-1]
print(first_part)
print(number)
```

Or, in short

```
print("2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654".split("-")[-1])
print("-".join("2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654".split("-")[:-1]))
```

**UPD**
in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

text="2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654"
separator="-"
first_part=$(echo "$text" | sed "s/$separator[^$separator]*$//")
number=$(echo "$text" | awk -F  "$separator" '{print $NF}')
echo "$first_part"
echo "$number"
```

Or, in short

```
echo "2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654" | sed "s/-[^-]*$//"
echo "2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654" | awk -F  "-" '{print $NF}'
```

Output:

```
2.3.7-SNAPSHOT
654
```

Comment: Hi Friend, thank you for your response, i need to use this in shell script , so i need the regex expression itself.

Comment: No problem. Updated with a variant suitable for use in shell script. Same.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tried this in python:

```
import re
text = '2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654'
first_part = re.sub('-[\d]+', '', text)
build_number = re.sub('[\d.]+-\w+-', '', text)
print(first_part)
print(build_number)
```

Output:

`'2.3.7-SNAPSHOT'`

`'654'`

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following in Bash:

```sh
s="2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654"
rx='([0-9.]+)-SNAPSHOT-([0-9]+)'
if [[ $s =~ $rx ]]; then
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/X0DyGs).

**Regex details**

- `([0-9.]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits or dots
- `-SNAPSHOT-` - a literal string
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative regex for getting digits at the end of a string: "[1-9]+$".

- `[1-9]`   denotes one time any digit
- `[1-9]+`   with the "+": any digit at
  least one or more times
- `$`   denotes the end of the string

In Python that would be:

```
import re
text = "2.3.7-SNAPSHOT-654"
regex = re.compile(r"[1-9]+$")
output = re.search(regex, text)
print(output)
#output: <re.Match object; span=(15, 18), match='654'>
```

Then you can get the rest of the string by slicing the text string:

```
print(text[:output.regs[0][0]-1])
#output: 2.3.7-SNAPSHOT
```